# surveyjs validation not hitting backend, nothing in dev tools network tab, text box works as normal

Tags: javascript, ajax, validation, surveyjs

The following is json taken from my surveyjs implementation. Everything works properly in the 10 page survey except for page1 shown below. It loads fine and acts just like a text box should however, it should check with http://www.example.com/check_application_code.php onblur or when the person clicks next (I do not care which). I do not see errors in my console, I do not see anything happen in the network tab, and when I watch the access logs on the server there is not hit to the backend when clicking next.

```
{
  "showQuestionNumbers": false,
  "checkErrorsMode": "onValueChanged",
  "pages": [
    {
      "name": "page1",
      "description": "Application Code",
      "elements": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "name": "applicationCode",
          "title": "You need an application code to apply. Please enter your code below.",
          "isRequired": true,
          "validators": [
            {
              "type": "async",
              "text": "Invalid application code.",
              "url": "http://www.example.com/check_application_code.php",
              "dataType": "json",
              "method": "get",
              "asyncValidators": [
                {
                  "name": "backendValidation",
                  "func": "function(params) { return params.hasOwnProperty('valid') && params.valid === true; }"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
```

Here are the JS script I am using to load surveyjs:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/inputmask@5.0.3/dist/inputmask.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/nouislider/dist/nouislider.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/survey-jquery/defaultV2.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/survey-jquery/survey.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/surveyjs-widgets@1.9.97/surveyjs-widgets.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/nouislider/dist/nouislider.min.css" />
```

A screenshot of the JS textbox:
[image: SurveyJS textbox]

The back end does work. When I call it with a browser it shows up in the logs and replies with the following:

```
{"valid":false,"message":"No application code provided."}
```

Not sure where to turn to next to get this working. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I was doing it wrong. You need to create a javascript function that will check the back end. As far as I know it is not built in to surveyjs. There is an example of this here: https://surveyjs.io/form-library/examples/javascript-async-form-validation/jquery